# Can someone check what is wrong in the rules of the $validate array in cakephp 2.5

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I just started using cakephp 2.5, and i am trying to validate form data using the $validate in the model.

The validation is always wrong even if i enter good data in the fields.

Can someone check what is wrong with my code??

The view file
adduser.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('user');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('Add User');
```

the controller file
UsersController.php

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
public $components = array('Session');

public function adduser(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->User->create();
        $this->User->save($this->request->data);
        }
    }
}
```

The Model file
User.php

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'alphaNumeric' => array(
                'rule'     => 'alphaNumeric',
                'required' => true,
                'message'  => 'The username must be letters and numbers'
            )
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'The email address must be valid',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', 6),
            'message' => 'The password must be at least 6 characters long',
            'required' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Thanks for everyone in advance

Comment: pr($this->User->validationErrors); after save and check what error it returns

Comment: i added the line after save and commented out my messages. i also added pr($this->request->data); in order to see the post array.                        Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [username] => admin
            [email] => admin@admin.com
            [password] => adminadmin
        )

)

Array
(
    [username] => Array
        (
            [0] => alphaNumeric
        )

    [email] => Array
        (
            [0] => This field cannot be left blank
        )

    [password] => Array
        (
            [0] => This field cannot be left blank
        )

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind your casing, naming conventions are very important in CakePHP in order for all the automagical stuff to work properly.

In your form, the model name should be `User`, not `user`

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I cant believe how i couldnt see it. I spent all the time trying to fix the rules